# PHP Conexion Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

¡Buenas tardes!

Tengo dos ficheros `php`, uno se conecta a `PHP`, y el otro incluye ese fichero y coge la variable conexión del fichero que se conecta.

Aunque en el de conexión no da error y pone que se ha conectado. En el otro pone como que no le estoy pasando la conexión, concretamente:

> mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

El fichero **conexión**  (connection.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
$connection = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "superuser", "******"); 
$openDB = mysqli_select_db ($connection, "medicalbd"); 

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Can't connect. Error: ".mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

if($connection){
    echo("CONECTADO");
}
else{
    echo("ERROR");
}

if($openDB){
    echo(" ABIERTA");
}

?>
```

el otro fichero:

```
class Record
{

    private $connection;
    private $pain;
    private $emotion;
    private $digestive;
    private $general;

    function _construct()
    {
        include "connection.php";
        if($connection){
            echo("perfe");
        }
        $this->connection = $connection;
        $this->pain = new Pain;
        $this->emotion = new Emotion;
        $this->digestive = new Digestive;
        $this->general = new General;
    }

    /**
     * This function make the array with all the params.
     * @param res The mysqli result.
     * @return this_array array<array> with all the records and the information of each pain.
     */
    private function makeArray($res)
    {
        $this_array = array();
        if($res === false) { 
            die('Error SQL: ' . mysqli_error($this->connection));
        }
        if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($a_res =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                $actual_array = array(
                    "record" => array(
                       // "total" => $res->num_rows,
                        "ID" => $a_res["IDRegistro"],
                        "date" => $a_res["fecha"],
                        "time" => $a_res["hora"],
                        "mail" => $a_res["correo"]
                    )
                );
                $this_array = array_push($actual_array);
            }
        } else {
            $this_array = NULL;
        }
        return $this_array;
    }

    /**
     * This functions sends a JSON with each record that the email or ID is var.
     * @param var It can be an  integer as the IDRecord or a String as the user's email.
     * @return this_array JSON with each record which its email or ID is var.
     */
    function getRecord($var)
    {
        if($this->connection){
            echo("coenctado");
        }
        else{
            echo("errorcito");
        }

        if (gettype($var) == "string") {
            $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM aniade_registro WHERE correo = '" . $var . "' ");
        } else {
            if (gettype($var) == "integer") {
                $res = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM aniade_registro WHERE IDRecord = '" . $var . "' ");
            }
        }

        return $this->makeArray($res);

    }
}
?>
```

El fichero de pruebas:

```
<?php
    include "record.php";

    $record = new Record();

    $aux = $record->getRecord(1);

    foreach($record_aux as $aux){
        echo($aux);
    }
?>
```

La salida que da es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado que el fichero se llama connection y que además están al mismo nivel (la ruta está bien).

No se muy bien porqué la conexión en el fichero de conexión es correcta pero en el otro no :(

¿Me podrían ayudar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Revisa bien tu código, porque el `echo("perfe");` no se está imprimiendo, significa que cuando creas la instancia de la clase no está tomando una conexión válida. ¿La clase `Record`  y el archivo de conexión están en la misma carpeta?

Comment: Y, no sé si es un error al copiar el código aquí, pero le falta un guión a tu método constructor en la clase `Record`, debería ser así: **`function __construct()`**  es decir, son **dos guiones**, no uno.

Comment: Claro lo que me extrañaba es que no salía el mensaje del constructor y efectivamente es lo que decías, le falta un _ al constructor ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: No te sale porque aunque no lo pongas las clases tienen un constructor por defecto, sólo que al no poner los `__` en `construct` no se estaba llamando ese método cuando creabas la instancia de la clase con `new`, sino el constructor por defecto que sería un constructor vacío.